# Sheldon Axler 3.117: How to understand the proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

I have trouble in understanding the proof of 3.117 in Linear Algebra Done Right (Third Edition). The Theorem is the following:

> 3.117$\quad$ Dimension of range $T$ equals column rank of $\mathcal{M}(T)$
>
> Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V;W).$
>   Then $\dim\text{range } T$ equals the column rank of $\mathcal{M}(T).$

The first paragraph of the proof given is the following:

> **Proof**
>
> Suppose $v_1,\dots, v_n$ is a basis of $V$ and $w_1,\dots, w_m$ is a basis of $W.$  The function that takes
>   $w\in\text{span}(Tv_1,\dots, Tv_n)$ to $\mathcal{M}(w)$ is easily seen
>   to be an isomorphism from $\text{span}(Tv_1,\dots, Tv_n)$ onto
>   $\text{span}\big(\mathcal{M}(Tv_1),\dots, \mathcal{M}(Tv_n)\big).$
>   Thus $\dim\text{span}(Tv_1,\dots,
>  Tv_n)=\dim\text{span}\big(\mathcal{M}(Tv_1),\dots,\mathcal{M}(Tv_n)\big),$  where the last dimension equals the column
>   rank of $\mathcal{M}(T).$

I don't understand that sentence "**The function that takes $w\in\text{span}(Tv_1,\dots, Tv_n)$ to $\mathcal{M}(w)$ is easily seen to be an isomorphism from $\text{span}(Tv_1,\dots, Tv_n)$ onto $\text{span}\big(\mathcal{M}(Tv_1),\dots,\mathcal{M}(Tv_n)\big)$.**".

I have checked [another almost same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2199235/how-to-understand-the-proof-of-3-117-in-axlers-book-of-linear-algebra), But I still wondering that how does $\mathcal{M}$ map $\text{span}(Tv_1,\dots, Tv_n)$ onto $\text{span}\big(\mathcal{M}(Tv_1),\dots,\mathcal{M}(Tv_n)\big)$.

I'm new in linear algebra, any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The following is my understanding. 
Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and suppose $w=Tv$ for some $w \in \text{range }T$ and $v \in V$.
$$
  w = Tv = T(c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n) = c_1Tv_1+\cdots+c_nTv_n
$$
Thus, we can see $w \in \text{span}(Tv_1,...,Tv_n)$. 
And we can have a linear map $\mathcal{M}: W \rightarrow F^{m,1}$, which is an isomorphism.
$$
  \mathcal{M}(w)=\mathcal{M}(c_1Tv_1+\cdots+c_nTv_n) = c_1\mathcal{M}(Tv_1)+\cdots+c_n\mathcal{M}(Tv_n)
$$
Thus, $\mathcal{M}(w) \in \text{span}(\mathcal{M}(Tv_1),...,\mathcal{M}(Tv_n))$.